# While loop collects rows from MySQL database multiple times instead of once

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this while loop here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $skuid = $row['skuid'];
  $sku = $row['sku'];
  $pagelink = $row['pagelink'];  
  $fitsbrand = $row['fitsbrand'];
  $fitsmodel = $row['fitsmodel'];
  $m_brand_cat = $row['m_brand_cat'];
  $m_frame_cat = $row['m_frame_cat'];
  $traynumber = strtok(parse_url($sku, PHP_URL_PATH), '-'); // for traynumber
  $endofurl = strrchr(parse_url($pagelink, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'); // for Search Engine Optimization URL Key - step 1 get URL
  $endofurl2 = strtok(parse_url($endofurl, PHP_URL_PATH), '.'); // for Search Engine Optimization URL Key - step 2 trim after . or .php
  $endofurl3 = trim($endofurl2, "/"); // for Search Engine Optimization URL Key - step 3 trim fist /
```

And here's my query:

```
$query = "SELECT
    skuid,
    replacementlenses.sku,
    replacementlenses.title,
    replacementlenses.description,
    replacementlenses.longdescription,
    replacementlenses.pagelink,
    replacementlenses.pagelinkrx,
    replacementlenses.imagelink,
    replacementlenses.imagelinksmall,
    replacementlenses.imagelink2,
    replacementlenses.imagelink3,
    replacementlenses.fitsbrand,
    replacementlenses.fitsmodel,
    replacementlenses.color,
    replacementlenses.colorcode,
    replacementlenses.polarized,
    replacementlenses.producttype,
    replacementlenses.fuselenses,
    replacementlenses.lenswidth,
    replacementlenses.lensheight,
    replacementlenses.frame_material,
    lenslist.brand,
    lenslist.model,
    lenslist.m_brand_cat,
    lenslist.m_frame_cat

    from lenslist, replacementlenses where replacementlenses.fitsbrand = lenslist.brand AND lenslist.brand LIKE '$brand%' AND replacementlenses.colorcode = 'C'";
```

As well as a screenshot of what the query should be returning, each row into an array:

[Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkSWF.jpg)

It then goes on to simply echo them into `<td>` on a spreadsheet. When using `var_dump($row)` I get the correct `skuid`, `title`, `color` and what not, but then on the next row down, everything is the same except for `m_frame_cat`, which is the only thing that seems to reiterate through the loop.

Here's my first `var_dump($row)` value:

```
array (size=25)
  'skuid' => string '34621' (length=5)
  'sku' => string '101002-C-00000000000' (length=20)
  'title' => string 'TITLE HERE' (length=56)
  'description' => string 'DESCRIPTION HERE' (length=56)
  'longdescription' => string '' (length=0)
  'pagelink' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=54)
  'pagelinkrx' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=54)
  'imagelink' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=55)
  'imagelinksmall' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=58)
  'imagelink2' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=55)
  'imagelink3' => string 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' (length=68)
  'fitsbrand' => string 'Black Flys' (length=10)
  'fitsmodel' => string 'Sonic Flys 2' (length=12)
  'color' => string 'Crystal Clear' (length=13)
  'colorcode' => string 'C' (length=1)
  'polarized' => string 'Non-polarized lenses' (length=20)
  'producttype' => string 'Replacement Lenses' (length=18)
  'fuselenses' => string 'N' (length=1)
  'lenswidth' => string '63' (length=2)
  'lensheight' => string '40' (length=2)
  'frame_material' => string 'P' (length=1)
  'brand' => string 'Black Flys' (length=10)
  'model' => string 'Sonic Flys 2' (length=12)
  'm_brand_cat' => string '433' (length=3)
  'm_frame_cat' => string '436' (length=3)
```

The next row should echo the information for the next row in the database, which is `Lucky Fly` for `fitsmodel`, but the next row is the same exact information yet the `m_frame_cat` now reflects Lucky Fly instead of all the rest of the info.

Is a `foreach` loop necessary here? How would I go about that?

Comment: Did you confirm your query is returning the results you expect?  To debug we would likely need to see the data and the query.

Comment: it smells like a reference somewkere or a duplicate in query result, but with this tiny part of code cant really find it. For the part youve shown it looks ok.

Comment: @MattS I've updated my post with my query, and I'm getting `num_rows` of 225, when the `fitsbrand` that I'm searching only has 15 rows in my database, so something must be going on there.

Comment: You probably have a one-to-many relationship from `lenslist` to `replacementlenses`, so `replacementlenses` values are repeated on each row.  I can't tell you the fix because I don't know your data or what you're expecting.

Comment: @MattS Understandable, do you think having all the data that I need be put into one table would be an easy remedy to this?

Comment: Probably not, but it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Getting into your app requirements and how to solve them is too broad a topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @MattS Yeah that makes sense, just trying to generate a spreadsheet. I'm going to give a shot at just remaking it from the ground up, I must've messed up somewhere